# Materialize Framework Nav Height Change

Tags: html, css, materialize

I been trying to make some adjustments to the height of the nav but it stays the same. I am not sure if it is fixed or i am applying the wrong CSS code. Here is my code:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="primary-color">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

style.css

```
.nav{
  height: 45px;
}

.navbar-fixed{
  height: 45px;
}
```

In my CSS i applied the Height property to nav class and also to navbar-fixed class but i wasnt successful. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

haven really used Materialize before but i'm guessing you need to add an !important tag in your .navbar-fixed. Materialize might have already set the height, and you need to override it